# Excel VB Script

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sets of data that contains some of the same information. This data is Names, b-days and other information about people. Each person is contained in one row through multiple columns.

Any ideas of how to make a script through VB to check all information from one person in one set of data with all of the data in the other set? I need to Highlight any names that are not in both sets. e.g.
(If another way in excel is available that works too) Cannot download any other software

**Set 1**

```
Somebody, Bob 9/2/2012 Male 
Someonelse, Joe 8/16/1950 Male
```

**Set 2**

```
Somebody, Bob 9/2/2012 Male
```

In this case I would need to highlight Someonelse, Joe in Set 1.

Acual data contains a few thousand people. Efficiency of script not a huge deal, as long as it gets the job done.

Comment: I'm sorry in Set 1, the two names should be on seperate rows

Comment: Fyi, you _can_ edit your original post

Comment: `In this case I would need to highlight Someonelse, Joe in Set 1.` If the data `Somebody, Bob 9/2/2012 Male` is in 1 cell then why not use a countif formula to find the data which is not present in set 2?

Comment: Do you have an example? I'm not very familiar with how Excel works. Thank you!

Comment: Sure see my reply in few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have an example? I'm not very familiar with how Excel works. Thank you! – Scape 27 secs ago

If your intention is to find the values which are not in SET 2 then you can use the Countif formula in conjunction with an IF formula. See the snapshot.

[image]

And if you want to highlight the cell then use conditional formatting using a formula :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Siddharth Rout! This helped a lot.